# Правильна ли постановка запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Как подготовить текст и подробный образец его заполнения, смотрите в ближайшем выпуске издания.

Answer (score 1):

Знаки препинания поставлены правильно: ***Как подготовить текст и подробный образец его заполнения**, смотрите в ближайшем выпуске издания.*

Пояснение

1. Это  **сложноподчиненное предложение** (СПП) с изъяснительной придаточной частью. Запятая ставится перед главным предложением.
2. **Одиночный союз И** соединяет  придаточное предложения (в нем союзное слово КАК)  и член предложения, в этом случае запятая перед И не ставится, как и в случае  двух однородных придаточных.

ПАС, § 115. Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении

Примечание, пункт г) https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134

Запятая не ставится: г) если придаточная часть, благодаря союзам и, или, включается в ряд однородных членов: Во время работы и когда вышел фильм, я не очень-то разобрался в нем (газ.);

3. Иногда в таких СПП  (с однородными отношениями и придаточной изъяснительной частью перед главной) используется **тире как неосновной знак**.  Но в этом случае (при данной структуре предложения и в деловом стиле) такой сильный знак не требуется.

§ 38. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

**Примечание** (возможное редактирование)

Как подготовить текст и подробный образец такой подготовки, смотрите в ближайшем выпуске издания.